# Series convergence given recursive condition

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence in R. Show that if there exists some $q \in (0,1) $ such that $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq q|a_n-a_{n-1}|$ for all natural numbers $\; n= 2,3,4...$ then $a_n$ converges. Why is $\;q=1\;$ not included?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1) Show that

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le q^{n-1}|a_2-a_1|$$

2) Now use that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}q^n=0\;$

Comment: You'd rather use convergence of $\sum q^n$...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Indeed so. That is the last part, at least in the proof that shows the given sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: but you don't need that if you know that absolute convergence $\implies$ convergence (the proof of which requires Cauchy sequences). Here $\sum(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM That'd be way too much to assume for such a basic exercise, but there are several venues to reach the same result, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

$q=1$ is not included, because the sequence
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5\dots$$
or
$$1, 2, 1, 2, 1\dots$$
would satisfy with equality the condition
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq q|a_n-a_{n-1}|$$
which in that case would reduce to 
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq |a_n-a_{n-1}|$$

And those sequences certainly do not converge...